# Rails Ajax call from controller without remote: true

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form for "Establecimientos" (Establishments), and when the user hits the submit button there's a validation that could lead to showing a modal dialog or redirecting to the "Establecimientos" index page. I've been trying with and without remote: true in the form having an error both times either with html or js calls. This is my controller (the form doesn't have remote: true):

```
def create
@establecimiento = Establecimiento.new(establecimiento_params)
  if !Establecimiento.exists?(:nit => @establecimiento.nit)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @establecimiento.save
        format.html { redirect_to establecimientos_url, notice: 'El establecimiento se cre&oacute; exitosamente.'.html_safe }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @establecimiento }       
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @establecimiento.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :action => 'create'}
      format.html { render :action => 'create', :formats=>[:js]}
    end
  end
  end
```

When the else block happens the *:formats=>[:js]* doesn't work, the content of my create.js.erb is displayed on a new page without any rendering as plain text (the console shows it was rendered as html). Any help is appreciated

**form partial**

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@establecimiento, label_errors: true,  layout: :horizontal, label_col: "col-sm-3", control_col: "col-sm-7") do |f| %>
...content
<%= f.form_group do %>
        <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
      <%= render 'duplicated_modal' %>
<% end %>
```

**create.js.erb**

```
<%@duplicated_establishment = Establecimiento.find_by_nit(@establecimiento.nit) %>
$('.modal-body').html("Ya existe un establecimiento con el mismo NIT (<%= j @duplicated_establishment.nit.to_s %>) ubicado en <%= j @duplicated_establishment.direccion_establecimiento  %>, desea crear una nueva sede?");
$('.modal-footer').html("<%= j button_to 'Crear nueva sede', new_location_path(@establecimiento), class: "btn btn-primary", "method"=>"post", remote: true%>  <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Cancelar</button> ")
$('#duplicated_conf_modal').modal("show");
$('#duplicated_conf_modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('.first_input').focus()
})
```

Using *remote: true* makes all calls as JS but there can also be HTML calls

Comment: If you want to respond with JavaScript, you should be using remote: true. I'm unfamiliar with the ":formats => [:js]" syntax, but it also seems counterintuitive to me. If you want JS, make a request in JS. Assuming we're going to use remote: true, can you please update your question to show both the .erb template with the submit button, and the create.js.erb response file?

Comment: As I said, the response could also be an html call, that's why I'm not using the remote: true. I used it before but then the problem is that there is going to be a JS call when I want it to be HTML. I'll add what the other files, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a request to be read as `format.js`, the easiest way is to hit the desired path plus `.js` at the end. As in `establecimientos_path + ".js"`.

I believe you can also do `establecimientos_path(format: "js")`.

Comment: The problem is in the `else` section, how could I request the action "create" there?

Comment: You should be able to just have `format.js` with no block and it will render `create.js.erb` appropriately.

Comment: Without the responde_to block? I did `respond_to do |format| format.js end` but it throws an UnknownFormat error

Comment: Have you verified that you are triggering `format.js` and not `format.json`? Because `respond_to { |format| format.js }` should work if that is the format of the request.

Comment: Since I don't have the remote: true option, the submit button triggers an html call, but I'm trying to send the JS call from the controller. Is the absence of that remote parameter the reason I'm getting an _unknownFormat_ error even with your suggestion... I've been stuck with this problem for 2 days and I don't know if it's going to be harder to leave remote: true and try to format the html from the JS call